# Changing view in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` called `myView` and I am getting it to show different kinds of data by saying `myView.setAdapter(peopleAdapter)` and `myView.setAdapter(animalAdapter)` and refreshing the ListView.

If I wanted to show an `ExpandableListView`, the adapter isn't a ListView so I cant say `myView.setAdapter(myExpListView)`. I get an error saying its incompatible.

So instead of setting an adapter to `myView` to display the expandable list view, I made a whole other view like so: `ExpandableListView myExpListView;` and I got my data set and set the adapter like so: `myExpListView.setAdapter(myExpListView)` and it works.

My only problem/question is this: I know how to swap adapters to show different data, but how do I swap views? So how do I swap from `myView` to `myExpListView` without starting a different activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Research into fragments, you'll love their usefulness.

Comment: @EvanB I shall read into these "fragments" you speak of. Any particularly useful links? Besides google?

Comment: @harikris Has a quick solution to your problem, but if you're looking for an easy, scalable solution, here's a link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: @EvanB Thanks for the link, I read into fragments because I'm sure I'll use them in the future but my project is small so I'm just going to use the visibility methods.

Comment: @Clay please edit your question: replace myExpListView.setAdapter(myExpListView) and myView.setAdapter(myExpListView) with the correct adapter instance names - you don't provide a view as an argument for setAdapter(). Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to control the views is via it's visibility method:

```
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
myExpListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and

```
myExpListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: this looks like an incredibly simple solution. Is it in any way different to using fragments as EvanB suggested?

Comment: Fragments are very nice. As always, there is a place and time to use every tool - depending on your requirements. If all you need is a simple way to manage/switch between the two views, then what i suggested above is efficient and simple to maintain.